VSCode under Windows keeps popping up a terminal window asking to update WSL even though I uninstalled the WSL extension
I'm using Windows 11 24H2.
I installed VSCode on it before I upgraded from Win 10.
The VSCode version is 1.93.1.
I used to have the WSL extension in VSCode, but I uninstalled it. Still, every time I start VSCode, it keeps popping up a terminal window asking me to "update" WSL. Even though, WSL itself is also no longer installed on my PC (anymore).
This is what I see in the pop-up:
Windows Subsystem for Linux must be updated to the latest version to proceed. You can update by running 'wsl.exe --update'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wslinstall

Press any key to install Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Press CTRL-C or close this window to cancel.
This prompt will time out in 60 seconds.

But if I run separately:
wsl --status
The Windows Subsystem for Linux is not installed. You can install by running 'wsl.exe --install'.
For more information please visit https://aka.ms/wslinstall

All the extensions I have in VSCode now are these:

Any idea what is going on here?

May I suggest to go through similar issues and/or log a new one VS-Code-Issues - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/233618. But before this please try to Search for any settings related to WSL or Remote-WSL and remove or disable them from File > Preferences > Settings. Delete the .vscode folder in your user directory (e.g., C:\Users \[YourUsername]\.vscode). And Navigate to C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\extensions and look for any folders related to WSL or Remote-WSL and delete them. Restart VSCodeand check if the issues still exists.

@SharadPaul Thanks! That helped. It hadn't occurred to me. Indeed, in the settings I found Terminal > Integrated: Use WSL Profiles. And after I deactivated that, the issue went away. Thank you again.

I faced the same problem with popup in vscode everytime even though I never used WSL before. After updating to the latest version this happened; I had been using windows 11 from quite a while.
The fix was to disable WSL from Windows Features:
Press Win + S, type Turn Windows features on or off, and open it.
Uncheck Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Click OK and restart your computer.
